# React performance issue. Render a list of async items waits for all promises to resolve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class ListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: 'bla'
    };

    new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve(props.value);
    }).then(res => {
      this.setState({ value: res });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.value}</div>
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const els = [];
    for (let i = 0; i< 1000; i++) {
      els.push(<ListItem key={i} value={i} />)
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {els}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When `App` renders it waits until all promises from `ListItem` resolve.

I want `App` to render immediately and `ListItem` to update step by step once each promise resolves.

I tried to move the `new Promise(...).then(...)` into `componentDidMount` but it did not help.

I know I can wrap `this.setState(...)` into `setTimeout` but it seems kinda hacky to me.

Comment: Why resolving the Promise at the Item component level and not at the List (App) component level ? Each time you will render your app, the ListItem component items will be created from scratch...

Comment: Can you share the code of your suggestion please?
Because I tried moving promises to App component but it doesn't look nice and works slower.